# How to use the value in a cell as a path for importing a CSV file

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I am working on a project to pull a CSV file and import it into Excel to validate a large number of data. The user will input the year and month of the file to be opened. These pieces of information will feed a cell which will create a path to the csv file. When pulling the code to import the CSV file into Excel, it will take the absolute file path and file name, but won't let me direct the code to pull the path that was created with the user import.

I have been modifying the code, added some other strings and variables, changed from a CSV to an Access DB instead and I am facing the same issue.

```
Sub RES()

    Dim RES As Worksheet
    Dim Book As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Sfile As String
    Dim Spath As String

    Set Book = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = Book.Sheets("Command")
    Sfile = Book.Sheets("Command").Range("M8").Value
    Spath = Book.Sheets("Command").Range("M11").Value

    Sfile = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Command").Range("M8").Value
    Spath = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Command").Range("$M$11").Value

    Range("L4").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Book.Queries.Add Name:="RES", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "   Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""Spath""),[Delimiter="";"", Columns=71, 
        Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    
        #""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source,
```

When running this, the portion:

```
Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""Spath"")
```

is giving me the runtime error:

> 1004 [DataFormat.Error] The supplied file path must be a valid
>   absolute path.

I would like to be able to provide the file path and name so the users can run different files as needed.

Comment: Well without sounds too dumb, are the UNC paths correct? Do you have extensions visible?

Comment: Paths are correct and the extensions are visible.

Comment: Your code constructs the Formula string with the literal string `"sPath"`. Instead,  construct the string using the `sPath` variable, similar to how you have done it with the `Chr( )`'s

Comment: Got it, thanks Chris!

Comment: Debug tip: add a string variable to hold the string you build for Formula.  Then view it with Debug.Print or Msgbox to make sure it's what you expect

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Book.Queries.Add Name:="RES", Formula:= _
    "let" & vbCrLf & _
    "   Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""" & SPath & """), " & _
    "[Delimiter="";"", Columns=71, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])," & vbCrLf & _
    "#""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source,
```